# TweetInvi - Cannot Unfollow Users

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

I have the following code that is intended to find the users you are following, and the users that you have requested to follow.  It then unfollows the one's that are not following you.  However it never actually seem's to work, however the AuthenticatedUser_UnFollowUser returns true. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
            private void AuthenticateUser()
                    {
                        CheckRateLimits();
                        Auth.SetUserCredentials(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _userAccessToken, _userAccessSecret);
                        authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
                    }

                    private void CheckRateLimits()
                    {

                        // Enable RateLimit Tracking
                        RateLimit.RateLimitTrackerMode = RateLimitTrackerMode.TrackAndAwait;
                        TweetinviEvents.QueryBeforeExecute += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            var queryRateLimits = RateLimit.GetQueryRateLimit(args.QueryURL);

                            // Some methods are not RateLimited. Invoking such a method will result in the queryRateLimits to be null
                            if (queryRateLimits != null)
                            {
                                if (queryRateLimits.Remaining > 0)
                                {
                                    AppendProgress("RateLimits Available : " + queryRateLimits.Remaining.ToString());
                                    // We have enough resource to execute the query
                                    return;
                                }

                                // Strategy #1 : Wait for RateLimits to be available
                                AppendProgress("Waiting for RateLimits until : " + queryRateLimits.ResetDateTime.ToLongTimeString() + "For " + queryRateLimits.ToString());
                                MessageBox.Show("Waiting for " + queryRateLimits.ResetDateTime.ToLongTimeString());
                                Thread.Sleep((int)queryRateLimits.ResetDateTimeInMilliseconds);

                                // Strategy #2 : Use different credentials
                                //var alternateCredentials = TwitterCredentials.CreateCredentials("", "", "", "");
                                //var twitterQuery = args.TwitterQuery;
                                //twitterQuery.OAuthCredentials = alternateCredentials;

                                // Strategy #3 : Cancel Query
                                //args.Cancel = true;
                            }
                        };
                    }

                  private void UnfollowUsersNotFollowingYou()
                    {
                        AuthenticateUser();
                        var toUnfollow = Examples.Friendship_GetUsersNotFollowingYou();

                        toUnfollow.ForEach(x =>
                        {
                            if (Examples.AuthenticatedUser_UnFollowUser(x.ScreenName))
                            {
                                AppendProgress("You have unfollowed " + x.ScreenName);
                                SaveUnfollowedUserIdToTextFile(x.ScreenName);
                            }
                        });

                    }
//From Examples Static Class                
                public static bool AuthenticatedUser_UnFollowUser(string userName)
                    {
                        var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
                        var userToFollow = User.GetUserFromScreenName(userName);

                        bool unfollowed = authenticatedUser.UnFollowUser(userToFollow);

                        return unfollowed;
                    }

    //Users Not Following You
                public static IEnumerable<IUser> Friendship_GetUsersNotFollowingYou()
            {
                var currentuser = Examples.User_GetCurrentUserScreenname();
                var followers = Examples.User_GetFriendIds(currentuser);
                var following = Examples.Friendship_GetUsersYouRequestedToFollow();

                var toUnfollow = following.Where(x => followers != x.FriendIds);

                return toUnfollow;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi. I have just verified and `unfollow` like follow seems to work properly. Could you please verify that you are using the latest version of Tweetinvi (0.9.13.0)?

Also please note that Unfollow will return success even if the user was not followed. This is what Twitter is returning and there is nothing I can do about that.

EDIT :

The problem came from the fact that @david-beamont was not retrieving the users properly.

Here is the code to get the following users :

```
var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser(); 
var friends = authenticatedUser.GetFriends();
```

Comment: If needed I can send you the project.  I have not had any issues with the Favouriting, or the following functions.

Comment: I am using TweetinviAPI.0.9.13.0

Comment: Well I will need to see your code works in live. I cannot see how this could not work. All the features you are referring to are working properly.

Comment: I have had a look at this again today, and it looks like my method: Friendship_GetUsersYouRequestedToFollow() here for getting the users you have requested to follow, I seem to have confused.  It looks like the method: Account.GetUsersYouRequestedToFollow() actually only returns users, that have a protected account, and you have sent them a pending follow request. that is still pending.  Is there a method I can use to get my followingid's?

Comment: `var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser(); var friends = authenticatedUser.GetFriends();` Twitter naming for following user is friend.

Comment: This now works fine thanks, to summarize it was because I was attempting to unfollow an account I had a pending follow request from. The method Account.GetUsersYouRequestedToFollow() only shows pending follow requests.  Not all followers.  Thanks Linvi